How to schedule a facebook post in nextjs?
I'm looking to make an app that can schedule and edit the post if needed a scheduled API for posting text and images to social media.
In my application, I want to post a Facebook post in 2 days, and if tomorrow I want to edit that post to change to a new text with different time or cancel it I still need to be able to do that. Is there a way I can do that in Nextjs?
I tried to see if cron-jobs in Vercel might do the trick but it's not working to configure multiple cron-jobs via API from what I've seen in the docs.
Anyone knows how I can do that?

You don't need cron to trigger this request at a specific time; Facebook's API already provides scheduled posts functionality. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages-api/posts#publish-posts

I Need it for twitter, linkedin, facebook, instagram, tiktok, youtube, and emails.
So I assume at least for one of them we'd need this feature.

Okay, but you still don't need a multitude of crons then, one will do. Store the times when you want to make your posts into your database, and then on each run select the posts to make, based on whether the current time is already greater - if so, make the post (and mark it as already posted in your database then, so that you don't select it again on the next run.)

do you know how i use the stored database to trigger the apis? this is my main question
since the cron needs to run to use the apis, say I need to sometimes not post anything and sometimes post 50,000 posts, I can run a cron every minute but it will timeout or run for very long time or get rate limited if it does 50k posts. besides it will be wasteful to run it every minute and perform a database search each time.

"and sometimes post 50,000 posts" - what, all at the exact same time? (Rather makes me doubt, that you're writing a legitimate app, and not a spam tool.) "or get rate limited if it does 50k posts" - API rate limits are not going to change based on what methodology you are using to trigger the whole process.

Hey, thanks for the feedback. I'm making an app that lets people manage their social media, which means I need to account for scaling, which is why I wrote 50k posts as an example.
will the cron be able to trigger all the apis I make in my next app all at once? or will a delay caused by the cron's loop cause some of the posts, say in the 50k example to be triggered a minute or more later?
I don't know how the cron-job integration with the api work in vercel, do you know if it won't ever run into rate limiting?

That you'll be able to get 50k posts out within a minute, is probably doubtful. You'd at least have to make asynchronous requests that don't wait for a response, instead of doing them one after the other. What limits you might run into on the side of each individual social network, is a different issue - they all ave their own limits and restrictions.

So basically what I understand from that, is you're suggesting I run a cron job every minute, check the database, and run the apis that match the database entries for scheduled posts.
Which means I need to hope I won't run into scaling issues, and there is no way to time it by a small margin such as every second since it will be too wasteful and will run into limitations as we scale up the start up.
If I understand you correctly, it means there is no way to ACTUALLY schedule an api with an ability to cancel it/reschedule using nextjs, correct? only the workaround you suggest
